# how to run multiple flask servers

Tags: python-2.7, rest, flask, webserver

I just built a REST API server using Flask. Now I want to build a web server (still using Flask) that handles all the template rendering. I'm confused on how to run multiple servers on the same machine, so how do I go about in implementing this? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/? There are many examples of people using different `VirtualHost` configurations that reading it may help you to understand and find.

Comment: You can run multiple Flask (or any wsgi apps) applications in a single wsgi app using [application dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/).